# How to get driving direction data from geo points?

Tags: android, google-maps, driving-directions

I want to get driving directions from source to destination from google maps. I written an app by following the below link.

http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/03/sample-google-map-driving-direction.html

But, finally i got GeoPoints only. How to convert them into directions like turn right, turn left , go straight 100mts. Is it possible to convert them or not ?? Is it correct method to get driving directions ?? or any other way to get directions ??

If anybody know these things please reply me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you got the complete direction details in this already given that instruction i.e. called legs step. Try to get the value of  node and description from the

```
<name>Head west</name>
<description>
    <![CDATA[go 250&#160;m]]>
</description>
```

this will given that step by step detail in each every  node. Store this value as string in list array also you can get the direction symbol from the those node

```
<IconStyle>
      <scale>1.300000</scale>
      <Icon>
           <href>http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/kml/paddle/go.png</href>
      </Icon>
      <hotSpot x="0.500000" y="0.000000" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
 </IconStyle>
 <ListStyle>
       <ItemIcon>
             <href>http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/kml/paddle/go-lv.png</href>
        </ItemIcon>
   </ListStyle>
```

hope you got solution

Comment: thanks for answer. Can you send any useful links regarding driving directions.